# Register for Darwin Notification and send event details via Callback - Codename One

Tags: ios, codenameone

I am trying to create a test App with Codename One that listens out for displayStatus change via Darwin Notifications and sends the events via callback to the Java side. I have very very little knowledge of C and almost no knowledge of objective C so most of the code i have for that part was lifted and joined from several places in the web. I have followed the developer guide but the build fails on the cloud. So far i have done the following:

In my start method i have this:

```
public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form("Xerveur", new LayeredLayout());

    hi.add(buildRootContainer()).add(buildRootChildContainer());

    Display.getInstance().callSerially(hi::show);
    registerForNativeCallback();
}
```

This registers for the native interface:

```
private void registerForNativeCallback(){
    NativeListener listener = NativeLookup.create(NativeListener.class);
    if( listener != null && listener.isSupported() ){
        Log.p("Setup Event Listener returned: " + listener.setupEventListener());
    }
}
```

The above code snippets are in the main class file. The NativeListener interface is simple:

```
public interface NativeListener extends NativeInterface {
    public boolean setupEventListener();
}
```

Now i have a simple callback class which is supposed to receive a string, having the required information from the native side:

```
public class NativeCallback {
    public static void receive(String payload){
        Log.p(payload);
    }
}
```

These are the contents of the ".m" file that was generated (the ".h" file is unmodified from what was auto-generated) and i edited:

```
#import "ca_ratelsoft_testing_testapp2_NativeListenerImpl.h"
#include "ca_ratelsoft_testing_testapp2_NativeCallback.h"
#include "CodenameOne_GLViewController.h"
#include <unistd.h>       // good idea in general
#include <stdlib.h>       // good idea in general

#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <notify.h>       // for all notifications


@implementation ca_ratelsoft_testing_testapp2_NativeListenerImpl

-(BOOL)setupEventListener{
    CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), //center
                                        NULL, // observer
                                        displayStatusChanged, // callback
                                        CFSTR("com.apple.springboard.displayStatus"), // event name
                                        NULL, // object
                                        CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);

    return YES;
}

static void displayStatusChanged(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo) {
    NSLog(@"event received!");
    // you might try inspecting the `userInfo` dictionary, to see
    //  if it contains any useful info
    if (userInfo != nil) {
        const void * keys;
        const void * values;
        NSString *payload = @"displayStatus$$$";    //delimeter: $$$
        CFDictionaryGetKeysAndValues(userInfo, &keys, &values);

        //key1=value1;key2=value2;

        for (int i = 0; i < CFDictionaryGetCount(userInfo); i++) {
            const char * keyStr = CFStringGetCStringPtr((CFStringRef)&keys[i], CFStringGetSystemEncoding());
            const char * valStr = CFStringGetCStringPtr((CFStringRef)&values[i], CFStringGetSystemEncoding());
            if( i > 0 )
                payload = [payload stringByAppendingString:@";"];
            payload = [payload stringByAppendingString:@(keyStr)];
            payload = [payload stringByAppendingString:@"="];
            payload = [payload stringByAppendingString:@(valStr)];
        }

        ca_ratelsoft_testing_testapp2_NativeCallback_receive___java_lang_String(CN1_THREAD_GET_STATE_PASS_ARG fromNSString(CN1_THREAD_GET_STATE_PASS_ARG payload));
    }
}

-(BOOL)isSupported{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

I get the following error when building a debug iOS app: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sq8f00nzf445gp0/f9e35511-c43f-4bb6-854a-f513ec8e3820-1500397464685-error.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lets start with the error, if you scroll to the bottom you will see `NativeListenerImpl.o` is mentioned. If you search for `NativeListenerImpl` in the file you will see the compilation code for that and the actual error right below it:

```
src/ca_ratelsoft_testing_testapp2_NativeListenerImpl.m:2:10: fatal error: 'ca_ratelsoft_testing_testapp2_NativeCallback.h' file not found
#include "ca_ratelsoft_testing_testapp2_NativeCallback.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
```

This happens because our optimizer is over eager to remove unused code and can't find the usage of callback. You can solve this by adding the following code to your main class:

```
boolean fakeVariable;

public void init(Object o) {
  // ... rest of code

  if(fakeVariable) {
      NativeCallback.receive(null);
  }
}
```

This is important. Don't make the variable private!!!

The variable is package protected and will always be false so that code will never occur. In theory some code can change that flag so the optimizer can't detect that and will be forced to leave that code in place.